# COUNT(*) from multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, count

How do I go about selecting COUNT(*)s from multiple tables in MySQL?

Such as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS table1Count FROM table1 WHERE someCondition
JOIN?? 
SELECT COUNT(*) AS table2Count FROM table2 WHERE someCondition
CROSS JOIN? subqueries?
SELECT COUNT(*) AS table3Count FROM table3 WHERE someCondition
```

**Edit:**

The goal is to return this:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| table1Count | table2Count | table3Count |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 14          | 27          | 0           |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Need more specifics - can you describe in words what you're trying to do?

Comment: try changing inner join to left join

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You can do it by using subqueries, one subquery for each tableCount :

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE someCondition) as table1Count, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE someCondition) as table2Count,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table3 WHERE someCondition) as table3Count
```

Comment: I want to count 3 (count) rows from first and only one count count row from 2nd. How I can do that ?

Comment: I came here trying to find out how to do the same in a firebird database. The syntax is slightly different: SELECT * FROM
(SELECT COUNT( * ) AS table1Count FROM table1),
(SELECT COUNT( * ) AS table2Count FROM table2),
(SELECT COUNT( * ) AS table3Count FROM table3)

Comment: add "LIMIT 1" to the end of sql

Comment: @Yiannis Mpourkelis: How can i apply group by here?

Comment: add `limit 1` at the end of the query to show a one-line result.

Comment: what if i have several tables and large datasets , would it be a performance penalty ? should i be switching to some other approach rather than sub queries or should i be improving indexes appropriately rather than looking for any other approach?

Answer (score 12):

You can do this with subqueries, e.g.:

```
select (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE someCondition) as table1Count, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE someCondition) as table2Count
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is simple approach to get purely the row counts from multiple tables, if there are **no conditions on specific tables**.

#### Note:

For InnoDB this count is an **approximation**.  However, for MyISAM the count is accurate.

Quoted from the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html):

> The number of rows. Some storage engines, such as MyISAM, store the
> exact count. For other storage engines, such as InnoDB, this value is
> an approximation, and may vary from the actual value by as much as 40%
> to 50%. In such cases, use SELECT COUNT(*) to obtain an accurate
> count.

Using the `information_schema.tables` table you can use:

```
SELECT 
    table_name, 
    table_rows
FROM 
    information_schema.tables
WHERE
    table_name like 'my_table%';
```

#### Output:

```
table_name    table_rows
my_table_1    0
my_table_2    15
my_table_3    30
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use UNION

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE someCondition
  UNION
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE someCondition
  UNION
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table3 WHERE someCondition
```

Comment: Union will give the results in individual rows instead of columns. The resultset the OP is looking for is a single row with 3 count columns

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in this way.

```
SELECT (select count(*) from table1) + (select count(*) from table2) as total_rows
```

You can add as many tables as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(table1.*) as t1,
    COUNT(table2.*) as t2,
    COUNT(table3.*) as t3 
FROM table1 
    LEFT JOIN tabel2 ON condition
    LEFT JOIN tabel3 ON condition
```

Comment: This will not work because all `counts` will return the same number for all three tables because it counts the same resultset

Comment: This is wrong. if you join multiple tables like this , it will multiply each record and will return false count for each

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but it works...

1.- Create a list of the tables you need to count rows.

2.- Put that list in the first column of a spreadsheet.

3.- In the second column, first row, use this formula:

```
="SELECT '"&A1&"', (SELECT count(*) FROM "&A1&") UNION"
```

4.- Fill down the formula.

5.- Copy the second column and paste it to do the query.

6.- Don't forget to remove the last UNION.