# Show count of multiple tables in one query

Tags: php, join, count

I have a question, I want to get counts of different tables in one query to show on a page...

This the query i wrote, But it's not providing correct result..

```
SELECT COUNT(U.uID) AS total, COUNT(P.cID) AS Catmame FROM `dev_web_user` AS U, `dev_web_categories` AS P
```

Please note all count is independent, now join etc...

Please help me on this...

Thanks & Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by joining them as two different temporary tables.

Try this way:

```
SELECT  * FROM
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM `dev_web_user`) T1 JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Catmame FROM `dev_web_categories`) T2 ON 1=1
```

**Sample Output:**

```
TOTAL   CATMAME
4       8
```

See working demo in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3d6ce/2).

Answer (score 0):

So try, this:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(U.uID) FROM `dev_web_user` AS U) as total,
  (SELECT COUNT(P.cID) FROM `dev_web_categories` AS P) as Catmame;
```

Comment: reading from the returned array must be reversed (at least on Oracle)

Comment: but i need all the counts as separate column a signal column.. is it possible?

Comment: I've edit my answer and by checking.. this maybe duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761240/count-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql

Comment: SELECT without FROM ?? which database accepts this query ?

Comment: @HalayemAnis As [SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) shows FROM clause is optional