# select COUNT with three table - mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select the `COUNT` with three tables with one single query (with `WHERE` conditions).

**Here is my code which doesn't work correctly.**

```
SELECT t1.count(id) AS car_model_count,t2.count(id) AS list_item_count,t3.count(id) 
    FROM `car_model` AS t1
    INNER JOIN `list_item` AS t2
    INNER JOIN `part_item` AS t3
    WHERE t1.user_id=3;
```

Comment: and what is the relations between these tables (parent <> foreign)? your join is incorrect - you are joining by what? better provide sample data from all tables and desired output.

Comment: No using foreign key but user_id is common all table.

Comment: You are missing `on` clauses.  Fix the query.

Comment: Your `JOIN` is invalid and your logic is wrong. You can't count from multiple tables independantly using that syntax. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761240/count-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql

Comment: I need any other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible by using `Sub-Query` OR `UNION` is possible to get the `COUNT` from multiple table.
Try this query :

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM `car_model` WHERE user_id=3 ) AS car_model_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `list_item` WHERE user_id=3) AS list_item_count,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM `part_item` WHERE user_id=3) AS part_item_count;
```