# Why I got an error when I want to count the frequency of data for multiple table in mysql? Flask is used to create web app

Tags: python, mysql

I want to create a dashboard widget in my web app. The first step is to count the frequency of pos, neg and neu in mysql from two table. I tried to find the solution in Flask, but not many. Hope u can help me.

The error that I got is:

> MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')

**Table in mysql:**

**ques9**

[image]

**ques10**

[image]

**My code:**

```
@app.route('/we/<string:programid>')
def we(programid):
# Create cursor
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

result = """SELECT(
(SELECT programid,sentiment, COUNT(*) 
FROM ques9 AS question9  
WHERE programid= %s
GROUP BY sentiment),
(SELECT programid,q10_sentiment, COUNT(*) 
FROM ques10 AS question10 
WHERE programid=%s
GROUP BY q10_sentiment ))"""

data_tuple = (programid, programid)
cur.execute(result, data_tuple)

program = cur.fetchall()

mysql.connection.commit()


if result > 0:
    return render_template('we.html',program=program)
else:
    msg = 'No Results Found'
    return render_template('we.html', msg=msg)
# Close connection
cur.close()
```

Comment: Because your queries are wrong. `SELECT programid,sentiment, COUNT(*) 
  FROM ques9  
 WHERE programid=%s
 GROUP BY programid,sentiment` might be an alternative for the first one as an example.

Comment: I have tried this method, but still got error

Answer (score 0):

The group by has to be after the where clause
So i posted all the python code, i thought  about  adding a try, but that you can look up

Your sql has some problems like the group an his own,l but your python code has also flaws, as you can see below. The variables for sql query and the data to send, i out there so that it looks somewhat cleanber

```
connection =   mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                     database='test_db',
                                     user='user',
                                     password='password')
cur = connection.cursor(prepared=True)
sql_update_query = """SELECT(
(SELECT programid,sentiment, COUNT(*) 
FROM ques9 AS question9  
WHERE programid= %s
GROUP BY sentiment),
(SELECT programid,q10_sentiment, COUNT(*) 
FROM ques10 AS question10 
WHERE programid=%s
GROUP BY q10_sentiment ))"""

data_tuple = (programid, programid)
cur .execute(sql_update_query, data_tuple)
connection.commit()
if (connection.is_connected()):
    cur.close()
    connection.close()
```

Comment: Given that programid must be 'test', it seems almost superfluous to include it in the SELECT

Comment: Hi select is not valid fist the first SELECT ( is wrong, so i give him a example how ot should look. because i hope he has mor text to come.

Comment: What should I do to count the frequency for two table?

Comment: I put Select with bracket as I want to count the frequency for two table...I got it from https://stackoverflow.com/a/36498752/7729836

Comment: so i corrected the complete sql code and also edited the python script you could also add a trx for problems too

Comment: @nbk Why I got `MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')`

Comment: please edit your post and add your new actual code. I am not sure where it hangs, because my code has no methods that need a column. Did you run your code in mysql workbench or phpmyadmin ?

Comment: I see, but you miss the part where you defined the cursor, it has a parameter. more i don't see.

Comment: When I write `cur = mysql.connection.cursor(prepared=True)`. I got this error `TypeError: cursor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prepared'`