# Select Count from Multiple Table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have multiple table like this
[Multiple Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTghO.png)

And I follow [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761240/count-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql), but still doesn't work with my goal. Is that posible to display (Select) the 'tbl_konsepLayanan' and count the 'tbl_ulasan' + 'tbl_layanan'? How posible?

This is my query so far

```
SELECT tbl_konsepLayanan.*,
   COUNT(*) AS tot_ulasan,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_layanan WHERE tbl_layanan.id_konsep = tbl_konsepLayanan.id_konsep) AS tot_layanan
FROM tbl_ulasan JOIN tbl_layanan ON tbl_ulasan.id_layanan = tbl_layanan.id_layanan
JOIN tbl_konsepLayanan ON tbl_konsepLayanan.id_konsep = tbl_layanan.id_konsep
GROUP BY tbl_layanan.id_konsep
```

The problem is if the service (tbl_layanan) not in review/zero review (tbl_ulasan) it won't display. My goal is it doesn't matter if the service did the review or not still be display in concept (tbl_konsepLayanan). Sorry for bad grammar, let the picture say

[The concept has 3 values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC68x.png)

[Just display 2 values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2jxr.png)

Sorry for can't display images because my reputation

Comment: Please include all of your information for a question in the question rather than links to outside websites. That way, in the future if someone ends up on this page while trying to fix a similar problem there's no worry that some of the information is no longer available. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @TomH and GordonLinoff I had include all of my information that necessary, the link to outside is just a picture can't display in post because my reputation below 10 rep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change join with right join on

> tbl_ulasan JOIN tbl_layanan

Comment: Not just on tbl_ulasan to tbl_layanan but tbl_konsepLayanan too, thanks sir